# DataTables dropdown buttons styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, metronic

I use DataTables in my project with Metronic v6 admin panel template. But DataTables dropdown export button styling doesn´t seem correct. I haven´t anything in DataTables stylesheet or DataTables js.

My dom code

```
dom: '<"row"<"col-8"B><"col-3 float-right"f><"col-1 float-right"l>>rtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'collection',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>',
                        className: 'btn btn-primary btn-elevate btn-icon btn-sm btn-square',
                        buttons: [
                            { text: 1 },
                            { text: 2 },
                            { text: 3 },
                            { text: 4 },
                            { text: 5 }
                        ],
                        dropup: true
                    },
                    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn btn-warning btn-elevate btn-icon btn-sm btn-square', titleAttr:'Copy', text:'<i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i>' },
                    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-success btn-elevate btn-icon btn-sm btn-square', titleAttr:'Excel', text:'<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>'},
                    { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn btn-google btn-elevate btn-icon btn-sm btn-square', titleAttr:'PDF', text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i>' },
                    { extend: 'colvis', className: 'btn btn-info btn-elevate btn-icon btn-sm btn-square', titleAttr:'PDF', text: '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' },

                ],
```

It looks like this:
[image]

But after I clicked the dropdown button it seems like this:
[image]

Comment: Broken images 
1. https://prnt.sc/qfieyo
2. https://prnt.sc/qfife1

I want to it should be shown like that : https://prnt.sc/qfigc8

Answer (score 0):

I use DataTables released version : https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js

Version: DataTables 1.10.20